# How do I sort an array in a natural order using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

all I want to do is sort an array, ascending, numerically.
I have an array with values like:

```
Array(
    [0] = > card12.jpg
    [1] = > card16.jpg
    [2] = > card4.jpg
    [2] = > card1.jpg
    [2] = > card2.jpg
    [2] = > card3.jpg
)
```

The array has 16 values in it.
I try to use `sort($myArray);`
but it sorts it like card1 then card11, card 12...

This is really giving me a hard time. Can you give me any solutions to sort this array from card1 to card16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
natsort($myArray);
```